# How to add more child page link to Breadcrumb function in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a subpage (child page) as a parent page as well, but the page link not appear on breadcrumb. The breadcrumb structure should be **"Home > About Us > Information > Title Page"** instead of **"Home > About Us > Title Page"**.

How do I fix that? should I add a code to my current breadcrumb function?

And here is the breadcrumb function in my website:

```
 /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Breadcrumb
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

function get_breadcrumb() {
    global $post;
    echo '<a href="'.home_url().'" rel="nofollow">Home</a>';
    echo ' / ';
        if (is_category() || is_single()) {
            the_category(' / ');
            if (is_single()) {
                echo ' / ';
                the_title();
            }
        } elseif (is_page()) {
            if($post->post_parent){
                $anc = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
                $title = get_the_title();
                foreach ( $anc as $ancestor ) {
                    $output = '<a href="'.get_permalink($ancestor).'" title="'.get_the_title($ancestor).'">'.get_the_title($ancestor).'</a> /';
                }
                echo $output;
                echo '<strong title="'.$title.'"> '.$title.'</strong>';
            } else {
                echo '<strong> '.get_the_title().'</strong>';
            }
        }
    elseif (is_tag()) {single_tag_title();}
    elseif (is_day()) {echo"Archive for "; the_time('F jS, Y');}
    elseif (is_month()) {echo"Archive for "; the_time('F, Y');}
    elseif (is_year()) {echo"Archive for "; the_time('Y');}
    elseif (is_author()) {echo"Author Archive";}
    elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) {echo "Blog Archives";}
    elseif (is_search()) {echo"Search Results";}
}
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

```
elseif( is_page() ){
    $items = [];
    $items[] = '<strong> '.get_the_title().'</strong>';
    $page = &$post;
    while( $page->post_parent ){
        $items[] = '<a href="'.get_permalink($page->post_parent).'" title="'.get_the_title($page->post_parent).'">'.get_the_title($page->post_parent).'</a> /';
        $page = get_post($page->post_parent);
    }
    $items = array_reverse($items);
    echo implode('/', $items);
}
```

// FYI I recomend you to find `dimox_breadcrumbs` , it has configured all you need already